# Facing issue while loading HDFS file into Hive

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to write data into hive using R Studio, for which first I am storing data into HDFS and from there I want to insert data into Hive.

Data stored in HDFS as : 
["TER0626974_achieved","TER0630327_achieved","TER0630520_achieved","TER0537124_achieved","TER0404705_achieved"]

Issue: Now the issue is reading this data from Hive.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbname.table_name (
    id string
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION "/hdfs/path/to/file";
```

We are able to insert this result into hive. But when try to read, getting below error.

> > archive_data <- dbGetQuery(hivecon, "SELECT * from Table") Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride, block) :
> >     org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException:
> >     org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException:
> >     Start token not found where expected

can this be the issue? JSON should start with { and not with array ([)?

Comment: Please show your table definition

Comment: CREATE external TABLE dbname.table_name
(id string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION "/hdfs/path/to/file";

Comment: You have `id string`, but you're trying to store arrays? Have you refereed to the Hive wiki on datatypes?

Comment: we tried (id array <string>) as well but it returned the same error.